# Android Studio Unit tests are failing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, mockito, powermockito

I am facing a problem while running my unit test on android studio.
If I run a unit test by right-clicking on the file and select run unit test option then unit test runs successfully, but if I use the command line option then my unit test are failing.
the command I am using `./gradlew testDebugUnitTest`
the error I am getting is

```
 Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:240)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:228)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:61)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)
    at com.walmart.rxbaggingimpl.businesslogics.AddBoxBLTest.<init>(AddBoxBLTest.kt:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.createTestInstance(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:197)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.createTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:182)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:204)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@7f432e48
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemToolClass(ToolProvider.java:178)
    at javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemTool(ToolProvider.java:158)
    at javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(ToolProvider.java:102)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:49)
    ... 56 more
```

code is

```
class MYTest: BaseTest() {
    private val api = APISERVICE(APIServiceClientMock)
    private val logapiServices = LogServices(APIServiceClientMock)
    private val myBL= MYBL(api, logspiServices, MockEventTrackLogger)


    fun getMockResponse(): StopViewResponse {
        val expectedResponse = StopViewResponse()
        expectedResponse.responseCode = Constants.SUCCESS_CODE
        expectedResponse.responseTexts = listOf("Success")
        expectedResponse setMockResponseAs SUCCESS
        return expectedResponse
    }

    @Test
    fun test1() {
        runBlocking {
            val data = MyModel()
            data.id = 1
            data.orderId = 1
            getMockResponse()
            rxPackBL.completeView(data)
            Assert.assertTrue(myBL.getCompleteEvent().value?.peekContent() is Success<*>)
            Utils.data= data
            myBL.completeView()
            Assert.assertTrue(myBL.getCompleteEvent().value?.peekContent() is Success<*>)
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code as well.

Comment: @KanwarpreetSingh question updated